# Image Processing : How to get luminance weighting value?

Tags: image-processing

Currently, I read a paper like [this](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjuqrSkkqzLAhWC2qYKHYe2CowQFgg6MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwinnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp%2Flocal%2FCDROM%2Ficassp04%2Fpdfs%2F0300493.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFqYpLGiI7F38zCciojabQZLaUnFg&sig2=RLF3hbpHykK4SETpRZqRVw), and [this](http://ijcsi.org/papers/IJCSI-8-4-2-13-20.pdf).

I'm looking for the methods about luminance weighting value.

When I saw the paper they explained so abstracted.
(for example, they explain like this : L_weight(i,j) is a positive single-peak function (e.g
triangular function or Gaussian function) value for the
luminance value at i-th row, j-th column of the k-th block.)

So I can't get a hint for getting luminance weighting value.
Would you please let me know for any hint to get luminance weight value or the equation of L_weight(i,j) ?

Does anyone know How to get  luminance weighting value? or any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a quick look at the first paper you linked.

The text tells you everything you need to know.

> Experimental result shows that a dark color has less color deviation
>   under different light source. Also, at high luminance, the color
>   components are easy to be saturated. Hence, those pixels with middle
>   luminance value in the pre-captured image are more important when
>   performance the light source estimation

They introduce a luminance weight in form of a single peak function like Gauss. So values with medium luminance have more weight than low and high values.
A weight between 0 and 1 should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I got it  really thanks. I didn't know that .